# Play2.0 Scala: Extracting data from config as a String

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using Scala, in a Play 2.0 project, I am trying to grab data from a config file.

At present I use the following code to extract a String:

```
val foo = Play.current.configuration.getString("foo")
```

I had expected to get a `String` object back, but instead an `Option[String]` object is returned.

I cannot find any Java docs describing the `Option[T]` object and calling the `toString()` returns `Some( foo )`.

The same happens when using the configuration methods to extract `Boolean` and `Int` values from the config - ie, `Option[Boolean]` and `Option[Int]` are returned.

Can anyone explain what this `Option[T]` object is and how I can access the value I want in the form that the `application` method call implies it will be returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scala, the type [`Option[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) represents an optional value of the type `T`. If you are used to Java terms, you could refer to an Option as 'a value that might be `null`'.

In Play they are used when getting the configuration because the string might not be present - if you would try to read it using Java, it would return `null`.

To get the config string you can use `getOrElse`, which lets you provide a default value in case the config string doesn't exist:

```
val foo = Play.current.configuration.getString("foo").getOrElse("bar")
```

Comment: I find using this pattern that I end up writing: *Play.current.configuration.getString(someId).getOrElse(throw new Exception("Key: " + someId + " not found")* a lot. Is there a better pattern to always throw an exception if the key isn't found in the config?

Comment: @sthomps I think you could just use `get`, which throws a `NoSuchElementException` if there was no element for the key. Best would be to have some reasonable default value though, if possible.